# How to debug Withdraw Function code and why is this risky

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to debug the following code and explain why such coding practice is risky and how it can be avoideded

```
function withdrawBalance()
{ uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];
if (msg.sender.call.value(amountToWithdraw)() == false)
{
throw;
}
userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is risky, because you update the balance of a user only after you used `call` on another address. The vulnerability in this code, called 're-entrancy', is that the a called contract could call `withdrawBalance` in their fallback function.

The attacking contract receives ether everytime they call `withdrawBalance`. But everytime they do, before their balance is checked, they do receive ether and just call `withdrawBalance` again, multiple times. Your contract's balance will probably be depleted by then.

This is the appropriate fix:

```
function withdrawBalance()
{
    uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];
    userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
    if (msg.sender.call.value(amountToWithdraw)() == false) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Putting the balance deduction before `call`, makes the re-entrancy attack impossible. Now, before an attacking contract calls `withdrawBalance`, their balance will already have been deducted, and the function will `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

this might cause a Reentrancy attack. I advice you to read this post as it it explains thoroughly this scenario :

https://hackernoon.com/smart-contract-security-part-1-reentrancy-attacks-ddb3b2429302